# Продолжение обсуждения исследования о Блаженном Августине

Tags: этимология

По обсуждению у меня создается стойкое впечатление, что автор весьма вольно интерпретирует источники (включая словари), а потом с блеском опровергает собственное их понимание. 
Ну хорошо, ладно, допустим, это я чего-то не понимаю.

Перейдем к главному.
Заявлена тема "Почему Августина называют блаженным" (Как я понимаю, речь идет о православной церкви). И каков ответ/вывод? 
Максимум, что можно почерпнуть из текста - мнение автора о различиях в понимании блаженства Восточной и Западной церковью (собственно, мнение это я пока никак не комментирую). Этого достаточно для ответа на поставленный вопрос? Мне - нет. Из понимания этих различий никак не следует святость/блаженство того или иного исторического персонажа. Максимум - снимает возможные недоразумения, хотя, на мой взгляд, недоразумений тут особых и не возникала. Никто реально не сводил православное блаженство Августина к процедуре католической беотификации. А если кто бы спутал, ответ легко найти и в миру, и в сети. И даже в словарях, составителей которых автор исследования почему-то возводит в ранг своих оппонентов. 
Короче, я могу воспринять это как некое непритязательное эссе о блаженном Августине (возможно автор тоже его так понимает), но тогда надо бы это как-то обозначить. По тексту получается, что автор претендует чуть ли не на документальноую достоверность. 
Или поставить вопрос так: "О разнице в понимании блаженства православной и католической церковью". Но тогда примера одного Агустина явно недостаточно, тем более что этот пример совершенно нехарактерен на фоне общей тенденции считать православными блаженными всех тех святых, которые признаны святыми до Раскола и лишь отдельных  католических - после.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И каков ответ/вывод?

Вывод в конце. Цитирую.

> Итак получается, что в исторической
> ретроспективе "блаженный" было
> синонимом слова "святой", а затем
> употреблялся св. отцами Восточного
> христианства в значении святой, "более
> низкого ранга". Хоть последнее
> значение и не было строго устоявшимся,
> тем не менее вполне объясняет причину
> закрепления за Августином наименования
> "Блаженный".

Comment: Это не ответ на заявленный вопрос. Не вижу никакой причинно-следственной связи между различиями в подходе и канонизаций конкретного святого.
Сказал уже, что это претендует максимум на снятие возможного недоразумения в понимании "блаженный" как "недосвятой". Хотя я воспринимаю такое недоразумения как явно надуманное. Ну вчитайтесь же в тексты, на которые Вы ссылаетесь. Нет там такого *объяснения*. Ориентируетесь на реально изложенные там факты, не додумывайте за авторов, ориентируетесь на то, что написано, а не то, что Вам пришло в голову при чтении. Для того и нужны ссылки, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Да и "причину" даже в таком виде совершенно не объясняет. Причины ищите в житиях святых. Понимаете, нельзя объяснять закон всемирного тяготения тем, что яблоко упало на голову именно Ньютона. Это всего лишь некое событие, связанное (якобы) с открытием, но никак его не объясняющее. Точно также, понимание различия в терминах *никак* не объясняет причину причисления Августина к блаженным. 
Остальное уже все сказал.

Comment: Добавлю.

>Этого достаточно для ответа на поставленный вопрос? Мне - нет.

А мне - да. И что тут обсуждать?  Для рецензирования исследования больше подходят комментарии. И ещё:

>на фоне общей тенденции считать православными блаженными всех тех святых, которые признаны святыми до Раскола и лишь отдельных католических - после

Нет такой тенденции. Определение слова "блаженный" из православной энциклопедии дано в исследовании.